# Three.js shader pointLight position

Tags: matrix, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

I'm trying to write my shader and add light sources, I sort of figured it out and did it.

But there is a problem, the position of the light source is incorrectly determined, when the camera rotates or moves, something unimaginable happens.

So I get the position of the vertex shader

```
vec3 vGlobalPosition = (modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 )).xyz
```

Now I'm trying to make an illuminated area

```
float lightDistance = pointLights[ i ].distance;
vec3 lightPosition  = pointLights[ i ].position;

float diffuseCoefficient = max( 
    1.0 - (distance(lightPosition,vGlobalPosition) / lightDistance ), 0.0);

gl_FragColor.rgb += color.rgb * diffuseCoefficient;
```

But as I wrote earlier if you rotate the camera, the lighting area moves to different positions.

I set the light position manually and everything became normal.

```
vec3 lightPosition  = vec3(2000,0,2000);
...
```

The question is how to get the right position of the light source? I need a global position, what position is contained in the light source I do not know.

Added an example: http://codepen.io/korner/pen/XMzEaG

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or codepen that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @gromiczek, Please don't ask people to use codepen or jsfiddle.  **Put the code in the question itself. Use [a snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) if you want it to run**

Comment: Added an example: http://codepen.io/korner/pen/XMzEaG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with `vPos`. Currently you do:

```
vPos = (modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz
```

Instead you need to multiply the position with `modelViewMatrix`:

```
vPos = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
```

You need to use `modelViewMatrix` because `PointLight.position` is relative to the camera.

Comment: Thanks, helped, but caused another problem) Is it possible to convert to a global position? Because I made a fog and there used `modelMatrix`

Comment: You're welcome! I don't see any fog in the current example, so instead of cluttering the comments up. I would instead encourage you to create a new question. :)

Comment: Please take a look at this post, maybe you can help me again :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873013/three-js-shader-pointlight-to-global-position

Comment: Glad to see you got it sorted, Seems you had seen an [example on my site](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/single_color_point_lights.html). I wonder why my example worked using modelMatrix.

Comment: @2pha `PointLight.position` hasn't always been relative to the camera, so it could be because you're using a version prior to that change. Another reason could be if you're manually setting the uniform values.

Comment: oh ok, the one I linked to uses release 70