# Three.js shader pointLight to global position

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

All hello, I'm doing a fog shader and trying to add light sources.

Recently I asked how to correctly determine the position of the light source, the question was solved, but another problem turned out, for the fog I use the position of the `modelMatrix`

```
vec3 fogVPosition = (modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 )).xyz
```

To calculate the intensity of light, I use the calculation of the distance from the light source to the point of fog.

```
float diffuseCoefficient = max( 1.0 - (distance(pointLights[i].position,fogVPosition) / plDistance), 0.0)
```

But how did I find out that the position of the light source is transmitted relative to the camera, so I can not calculate the distance correctly and the light source changes its position if I shuffle the camera.

Here's an example of what I did http://codepen.io/korner/pen/BWJLrq

In this example, it can be seen that the light sources are not positioned correctly on the surface.

My goal is done as on this screen: http://dt-byte.ru/f97dc222.png

This works if you put the global position of the light source manually, I just need to somehow get the position of the light source in the global position `pointLights[i].position`

**The problem is solved!**

Forgive my friends, I stepped, I did not realize that you can add a `modelViewMatrix`

I added one more variable `ligVPosition`

```
fogVPosition = (modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 )).xyz;
ligVPosition = (modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 )).xyz;
```

Then changed the `fogVPosition` to the `ligVPosition`

```
float diffuseCoefficient = max( 1.0 - (distance(pointLights[i].position,ligVPosition) / plDistance), 0.0)
```

Now everything works fine!

Comment: Are you just searching for how to convert the position relative to the camera to it's world position?

Comment: Yes, this is what I need)

Comment: Thank you, problem solved :)